# Can Microsoft Bing Speech be configured to return only numbers / letters?

Tags: voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

Can the Microsoft Bing Speech API be configured to only return numbers and letters, as opposed to full words?

The use case is translating Canadian postal codes. Ex. M 1 B 0 R 3. Microsoft may return "Em 1 Be 0 Are 3"

Our audio file is 8000hz and encoded with "M-ULAW". We have no flexibility in changing the sample rate or encoding. We are using the "SMD" scenario, but I can't find any documentation on what this does. Base request URI:

`https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize?scenarios=smd&appid=D4D52672-91D7-4C74-8AD8-42B1D98141A5&device.os=your_device_os&version=3.0`

Is there a way to get a more accurate response from Microsoft for this use case?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Microsoft's Custom Speech Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Custom-Speech-Service/cognitive-services-custom-speech-home) (previously known as the Custom Recognition Intelligent Service, or CRIS) to create and use a [custom language model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/customspeech-how-to-topics/cognitive-services-custom-speech-create-language-model).

The [guidelines for transcription of custom language models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-speech-service/customspeech-how-to-topics/cognitive-services-custom-speech-transcription-guidelines) say "Common acronyms can be left as a single entity without periods or spaces between the letters, but all other acronyms should be written out in separate letters, with each letter separated by a single space" and include this example:

```
Original text               After normalization
-----------------------     ---------------------------
play OU812 by Van Halen     play O U 8 1 2 by Van Halen
```

So following their guidelines, your custom language model will be a file where each line looks something like this:

```
M 1 B 0 R 3
```

You can easily generate a file containing thousands of examples of Canadian postal codes based on the structure of the codes, which in regular expression format looks like this:

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]
```

(The above expression is taken from [this answer about validating postal codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1146231/122762).)

By doing this you're telling the recognizer what sort of things you're expecting people to say, and helping it choose when there are multiple possibilities for a sound (e.g. "U" vs. "you").  I think it will make a huge difference in the results you get.

Comment: So what I did: I uploaded a newline separated file of all Canadian postal code prefixes (M1B, M8X, B3L, etc), as opposed to a file of all possible postal codes in the Language Model datasets. The results still aren't perfect. For example, "R 2 G" is still being transcribed as "R 2 C". I think the Acoustic Language Model might be a better bet, but that would require the gathering of many, many sample audio files.

Comment: Right I forgot to mention that especially because you're using µ-law/mu-law encoding, creating your own acoustic model could also be helpful.  I do think the custom language model is going to be the best thing you can do.  Some recognition systems (e.g. pocketsphinx) let you specify a grammar as opposed to a statistical language model, and that would be worth trying also.