# Google Speech API letter and digit

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am currently using the **Google Speech Recognition API** in java to repeat what user input when spoken. The program works for words and numbers but fails when I use letters and postal code.

For example, I say *M3X 5C9*: it thinks I am saying "*em 3 ex 5 see 9*".

**Is there a way to make it recognize only letters and digits?**

Comment: Currently there is not an option to instruct Speech API to read single letters or numbers. The purpose is to identify spoken words; nevertheless, in this question [Can the Google Speech API be configured to return only numbers / letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310657/can-the-google-speech-api-be-configured-to-return-only-numbers-letters) there are some suggestions to use speechContexts, this can improve a bit the accuracy.